# LaTex - Turn off alternating page numbering and paragraph indenting in memoir / bianchimod

Tags: formatting

I'm using a Latex template which uses memoir style and `\chapterstyle{bianchimod}`. I noticed that on every page there's an alternating behavior of the paragraph and the page number positions. Paragraphs are indented or not and the page number is one time on the left and the next page on the right side.

Is there a way to turn this off and keep the formatting as seen below on the first page?

[image]

The layoutsetup.tex file looks the following:

```
%% Memoir layout setup

%% NOTE: You are strongly advised not to change any of them unless you
%% know what you are doing.  These settings strongly interact in the
%% final look of the document.

% Dependencies
\usepackage{ETHlogo}

% Turn extra space before chapter headings off.
\setlength{\beforechapskip}{0pt}

\nonzeroparskip
\parindent=0pt
\defaultlists

% Chapter style redefinition
\makeatletter

\if@twoside
  \pagestyle{Ruled}
  \copypagestyle{chapter}{Ruled}
\else
  \pagestyle{ruled}
  \copypagestyle{chapter}{ruled}
\fi
\makeoddhead{chapter}{}{}{}
\makeevenhead{chapter}{}{}{}
\makeheadrule{chapter}{\textwidth}{0pt}
\copypagestyle{abstract}{empty}

\makechapterstyle{bianchimod}{%
  \chapterstyle{default}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{\normalfont\Large\sffamily}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\Large\sffamily}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{%
    \chapnamefont\centering\@chapapp}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont {\thechapter}}
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\huge\sffamily}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
    \hrule\vskip\onelineskip \centering \chaptitlefont\textbf{\vphantom{gyM}##1}\par}
  \renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{\vskip\onelineskip \hrule\vskip
    \afterchapskip}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternonum}{%
    \vphantom{\chapnumfont {9}}\afterchapternum}}

% Use the newly defined style
\chapterstyle{bianchimod}

\setsecheadstyle{\Large\bfseries\sffamily}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\large\bfseries\sffamily}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\bfseries\sffamily}
\setparaheadstyle{\normalsize\bfseries\sffamily}
\setsubparaheadstyle{\normalsize\itshape\sffamily}
\setsubparaindent{0pt}

% Set captions to a more separated style for clearness
\captionnamefont{\sffamily\bfseries\footnotesize}
\captiontitlefont{\sffamily\footnotesize}
\setlength{\intextsep}{16pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{1pt}

% Set section and TOC numbering depth to subsection
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
\settocdepth{subsection}

%% Titlepage adjustments
\pretitle{\vspace{0pt plus 0.7fill}\begin{center}\HUGE\sffamily\bfseries}
\posttitle{\end{center}\par}
\preauthor{\par\begin{center}\let\and\\\Large\sffamily}
\postauthor{\end{center}}
\predate{\par\begin{center}\Large\sffamily}
\postdate{\end{center}}

\def\@advisors{}
\newcommand{\advisors}[1]{\def\@advisors{#1}}
\def\@department{}
\newcommand{\department}[1]{\def\@department{#1}}
\def\@thesistype{}
\newcommand{\thesistype}[1]{\def\@thesistype{#1}}

\renewcommand{\maketitlehooka}{\noindent\ETHlogo[2in]}

\renewcommand{\maketitlehookb}{\vspace{1in}%
  \par\begin{center}\Large\sffamily\@thesistype\end{center}}

\renewcommand{\maketitlehookd}{%
  \vfill\par
  \begin{flushright}
    \sffamily
    \@advisors\par
    \@department, ETH Z\"urich
  \end{flushright}
}

\checkandfixthelayout

\setlength{\droptitle}{-48pt}

\makeatother

% This defines how theorems should look. Best leave as is.
\theoremstyle{plain}
\setlength\theorempostskipamount{0pt}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: "thesis"
%%% End:
```

Comment: your question isn't very clear and you haven't provided a usable example, but I would guess that you want `\documentclass[oneside]{...}`

Comment: Where do you want the page number to be? Left, right, centre?

Comment: @samcarter I would like to have everything as seen in the first picture section 2.2. Paragraphs flushleft, page number on the right side. The headers would be nice to have as in the first picture page 6.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the template uses `\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage]{memoir}. Can I add onside within the [ ] brackets?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle this : `\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage, oneside]{memoir}` worked and did do the trick :) thank you very much

Comment: you can yes, but anything intended to be printed would normally use a twoside layout with different layout on left and right hand pages.

Comment: To get the page numbers on the right side: `\makeevenfoot{plain}{}{\thepage}{}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the document is mostly intended for onscreen viewing you can add `oneside` to the `\documentclass` options to disable the separate layout for left and right pages, but for almost all documents that are intended to be printed using both sides of the paper, the default `twoside` layout would be more natural.

Comment: thanks :) I'll keep it in mind in case I'll print the document.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not perfectly clear, but I think you want to have the page number and heading aligned with the text, and not outside of it as in the second page of your example (and first page already for the page number).

I had the same issue (also using the template from the department of informatik at ETH), and indeed as [David](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/467393/120361) suggests you can simply add `oneside` in the `\documentclass`.

However, if you still want to have an alternative behaviour, (for printing issues or else) you can still align the page numbers and page headings with the `twoside` option.

Please consider the following description from the [official memoir class documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/memoir/memman.pdf)

> *The page styles provided by the class are*
>
> *ruled*: The footer contains the folio at the outside. The header on verso pages contains the
>   chapter number and title in small caps at the outside; on recto pges the section title is
>   typeset at the outside using the normal font. A line is drawn underneath the header.
>
> *Ruled*: This is like the ruled style except that the headers and footers extend into the foreedge margin.

You thus want to have

```
\if@twoside
    \pagestyle{ruled}
    \copypagestyle{chapter}{ruled}
\else
    \pagestyle{ruled}
    \copypagestyle{chapter}{ruled}
\fi
```

Notice the `Ruled` in your example is changed to `ruled`.